# Render character in bounding box

Tags: libgdx

i'm rendering an attack animation with the following code:

```
currentFrame = attackAnimation[3].getKeyFrame(stateTime, false); //3 : left, 2: right
batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY());
```

This renders the CurrentFrame on the x and y position of the character. This works fine for the right animation as you can see here:

[image]

but when i apply the same code for left for example it doesn't draw the character on the correct place and like "pushes himself away" from the bottom left corner and leaving the bounding box.

What am I doing wrong or what am I not seeing?

[image]

```
setGameObject(new Sprite(txtIdle[2]));
setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
setOrigin(getWidth() /2.0f, getHeight() /2.0f);
setPosition(500, 500);
```

this code sets an idle image and the size of the bounding box (and the sprite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is drawing the bottom-left corner of the texture at the given coordinate (x,y). In the first case, it works because Link's body has an edge to the far left and so he appears inside the box. In the second case, however, the far left side of the texture is the end of the sword, so it places this part in the box and "draws out" from there.

One possible way to fix this would be to render the sword separately from Link's body. The bounding box is just large enough to contain Link, so you could render the sword just outside the bounding box at position `(box corner.x + box width, box corner.y)` when facing right and at `(box corner.x - sword width, box corner.y)` when facing the left.

Comment: I see, so how do i fix it?

Comment: See my edit for one possible fix.

Comment: isn't there a way to draw from the origin center of the bounding box?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: isn't there a way to draw the character in the center rather then drawing from the bottom-left corner? "It is drawing the bottom-left corner of the texture at the given coordinate (x,y)"

Comment: You could render from the center of the texture by a simple translation of the rendering point by (-texture.width/2, texture.height/2) (assuming +y is down.) 

The problem is that Link's center, in terms of texture coordinates, is different between the left- and right-facing textures. You can see this more easily if you place one of the textures above the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and set the bounding box size depending on the sprite size. If for some reason your sprites(animation frames) have different sizes, then use the largest one's size.